# Как определить форму экрана?

Tags: java, android

Экран смартфона может иметь врезку в виде камеры (или чего-то ещё)
Для правильной работы программы нужно узнать есть на устройстве эта врезка(или экран прямоугольный) и высоту ВСЕГО экрана без этой врезки. Если я использую команду

```
display.getSize(resolution);
```

то получаю высоту экрана без врезки, НО и без высоты панели Back\Home\Menu!!!
Если использую команду

```
display.getRealSize(resolution);
```

то получаю высоту экрана вместе с высотой панели Back\Home\Menu (это мне подходит), НО и вместе с высотой врезки (а это мне не нужно). Подскажите, как получить высоту экрана без высоты врезки, но с высотой панели Back\Home\Menu?

Comment: [Высота панели навигации](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264361)

Comment: вам надо не экран мерять, а размеры вашего View

Comment: @Вася Воронцов, с помощью этого способа я получаю высоту навигационной панели, а мне нужна высота врезки для камеры. Как её получить?

Comment: @Style-7, View я рисую в классе SurfaceView. По высоте полученный View больше чем экран. Я просто должен правильно вывести View на экран.

Comment: А к `getSize` уже нельзя прибавить? Пусть a - высота врезки, b - высота "изменяемой" части (как называется?) экрана, c - высота панели навигации. Тогда `getSize` = b, по ссылке = c. b + c = высота экрана без высоты врезки

Comment: @Вася Воронцов, примерно так и сделал. Получилось